# Main Activity is not coming after Splash screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, splash-screen

This is my code. The main activity won't run after the splash screen and no errors appeared. The app is getting crashed after the splash screen.

**Splash Activity**

```
package com.example.collegematch;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();   


        Thread thread = new Thread(){

            public void run(){
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this , MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. It is considered bad practice by Google to have a fake loading on Splash screens. 2. Can you share the exception log (from logcat)?

Comment: It's very difficult to debug a crash without a stack trace. See [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](/q/23353173) for Android-specific advice, and [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](/q/3988788) for advice on what to do once you have the stack trace.  If you still need help, edit your question to include the **complete stack trace**, as well as **which line of your code** the stack trace points to.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code to:

```
val handler = Handler(mainLooper)
        handler.postDelayed(
            {
                startActivity(
                    new Intent(SplashActivity.this , MainActivity.class)
                );
                finish();
            }, 1000
        )
```

It is not recommended to make splash screen like this. Please read [this](https://shishirthedev.medium.com/the-right-way-to-implement-a-splash-screen-in-android-acae0e52949a).